# Can't View Home Page Wordpress Localhost Mamp

Tags: php, localhost, mamp

I have set up a local wordpress environment which is a carbon copy of a live site so we can work on a new design.

The live site database has been copied into localhost php myadmin and is working fine.

The localhost site is situated in a folder called /3dfc/ inside the htdocs folder.

So i have a site address of - http://localhost:8888/3dfc -

I can view the whole website no issues, apart from the homepage.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: What happens when you try to load the homepage? Do you get an error message? Blank page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

goto wp-admin

setting --> reading

and set your front page to the page which you want to set as home page.

Comment: nope didn't work - the home page has already been set.
I get the error "Safari can't open the page "localhost/3dfc/ because safari can't connect to the server localhost

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I post a similar question here:
[Home Page Wordpress on Free MAMP does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44798182/home-page-wordpress-on-free-mamp-does-not-work)

after several debug I found that this guide is correct:
http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php

You need:
1. In /etc/hosts add your virtual hosts like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 mywebsite
```

before I only used localhost because I hoped to use this host in browser but I found it's required to define a new host like mywebsite.

2. In httpd.conf I activated:

   Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
3. In this file I have:

   NameVirtualHost *:8888

   ServerAdmin myuser@gmail.com
       DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
       ServerName mywebsite
       ErrorLog "logs/mywebsite-error_log"
       CustomLog "logs/mywebsite-access_log" common