# Home Page Wordpress on Free MAMP does not work

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I have installed MAMP (free version) on my Mac and I see the Start Page but I have a problem:

I deployed wordpress but browser say unable to connect (basically I cannot see wordpress page in browser).

In Document Root if I put a static html file I am able to see it in the browser. I am also able to see wordpress administrative pages and all other pages but home page. I have 8888 and 8889 for php and mysql ports. I do not know how to debug the issues. php, apache and mysql do not report any particular problems.

I configured virtual hosts following this guide:
http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php

The strange thing when I put http://localhost:8888/mywebsite in the browser it is redirected to localhost/mywebsite.

In /etc/hosts I have:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

In httpd.conf I activated:

```
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and in this file I have:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8888

<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerAdmin myuser@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/mywebsite-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/mywebsite-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope someone could help.

Comment: An update. I am able to see administration http://localhost:8888/mywebsite/wp-admin/ but not the actual website: http://localhost:8888/mywebsite/

Comment: Second Update. I realized all website pages are visible but home page. I do not why.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. After several debugging I found that this guide is correct: http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php

You need: 1. In /etc/hosts add your virtual hosts like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 mywebsite
```

before I only used localhost because I hoped to use this host in browser but I found it's required to define a new host like mywebsite.

2. In httpd.conf I activated:

   Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
3. In this file I have:

   ServerAdmin myuser@gmail.com
       DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
       ServerName mywebsite
       ErrorLog "logs/mywebsite-error_log"
       CustomLog "logs/mywebsite-access_log" common